# struts2 drop down

Tags: struts2

I need to create a drop down menu in struts2 from List. How can I create an action class so that when a .jsp page is loaded, it populates the list first?

i found this link http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/ , it works too but for it work user must go to http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/selectAction.action to make it work but what if someone were to directly go to select.jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a .jsp, you could load the dropdown with a scriptlet before you render the `<s:select>` tag.

However, it's better practice to allow the action to perform the loading and hide the .jsp files under /WEB-INF so they're not directly accessible.  A common approach to perform this is the [Prepare interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/prepare-interceptor.html).

If you've got it in your interceptor stack, it will automatically invoke any method with the following name in your action **before invoking the requested method**:

- prepare{MethodName}()
- prepareDo{MethodName}()
- prepare()

That means you can do something like the following in your Action:

```
public class YourAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String prepare(){
         // populate your drop down object
    }   

    public String view(){
         // forward to your jsp
         return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Then all you have to do is call your action's view() method and prepare will be called first by Struts.

Comment: So, let me see if I get this right: I implement prepare() method in the class that forwards it to the page that uses that list?

Say, if that action class has 3 diff forwards, wouldn't it be called for each forward and not all of them will be using that list. Am I right?

Comment: Not so.  You can use the 'excludeMethods' parameter to prevent it from running on certain method names (see section in Workflow interceptor on excluding: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/workflow-interceptor.html).  There is also the 'alwaysInvokePrepare' parameter that you can set to false so that only prepare methods that are suffixed by your method name are invoked (i.e. if you had a view() method in your Action, and alwaysInvokePrepare = false, only prepareView() would be invoked).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Would you also know how can I implement dependent drop downs?

Comment: Thanks Pat, I am trying to follow that but I am stuck on how to call a method of an action when first drop value is selected! Would jquery be able to handle list as a result or does it have to JSON?

Comment: You would have to create an onchange event handler on the dropdown that issued an ajax request to your action.  The action would then have to create the response in a format that would be easiest for you to work with.  I would recommend converting your list into a JSON object and then using that object to create your new, dependent dropdown.  I'm not sure what version of Struts2 you're using, but if it's not already bundled, this is a good plugin: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin

Comment: Thank you once again, Pat. I am able to create one now that accpets list. But, that causes some hibernate issues. I have created another question for that. If that can't be fixed, I will have to use JSON to fix it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376716/struts2-hibernate-returning-a-list-causing-hibernate-to-fetch-data-from-all-rela