# how to populate drop down with prepare interface

Tags: java, struts2

i saw a link [struts2 drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323294/struts2-drop-down) but i am unable to understand how to use prepare interceptor.
how will request be forwarded to jsp and view method will be called

can anyone give me a example?

```
  public class YourAction extends ActionSupport {

public String prepare(){
     // populate your drop down object
}   

public String view(){
     // forward to your jsp
     return SUCCESS;
}

 }
```

Comment: Prepare runs before the parameters are set, before validate is run, and clearly before execute is called.  You could populate a drop down in execute() just as well as prepare().  There is no difference if you don't need values to be set to determine what will be in the drop down.  If use some form of DI then prepare should not be needed much.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors are invoked before and/or after the execution of action depending on the interceptor type.In your case the prepare interceptor is used. To understand the workflow of the interceptors in general take a [look here](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-interceptors-example-1.html)

Regarding the prepare interceptors you should read [this article](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/prepare-interceptor.html) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use method name `prepareView()` instead of `prepare()`.

As, `prepare()` will be called before any method in this class and `prepareView()` will be called only before `view()`.